# Given semiperimeter and radii of inscribed and circumscribed circles, find the side lengths of triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles, roots, cubics

Consider $\triangle ABC$ with side lengths $a,b,c$,
semiperimeter $\rho=\tfrac12\,(a+b+c)$,
inradius $r$ and circumradius $R$.
Let $u=\rho/R,\ v=r/R$,
$a'=a/R,\ b'=b/R,\ c'=c/R$.

Given $u,\,v$,
we can find 
$a',\,b',\,c'$ as roots of cubic equation

\begin{align}
x^3-2\,u\,x^2+(u^2+v^2+4\,v)\,x-4\,u\,v&=0
\tag{1}\label{1}
,
\end{align}

and the side lengths in increasing order $a\le b\le c$
can be expressed as

\begin{align}
a&=
\tfrac23\,R\,\left(u+\sqrt{u^2-3\,v\,(v+4)}\,
    \cos(\phi+\tfrac{2\pi}3)
  \right)
\tag{2a}\label{2a}
,\\
b&=
\tfrac23\,R\,\left(u+\sqrt{u^2-3\,v\,(v+4)}\,
    \cos(\phi-\tfrac{2\pi}3)
  \right)
\tag{2b}\label{2b}
,\\
c&=
\tfrac23\,R\,\left(u+\sqrt{u^2-3\,v\,(v+4)}\,
    \cos(\phi)
  \right)
\tag{2c}\label{2c}
,\\
\phi&=
      \tfrac13\,\arctan\left(
        {3\,\sqrt3\,v\,\sqrt{u^2\,(2\,(27-(5-v)^2)-u^2)-v\,(v+4)^3}}
        ,
        {u\,(9\,v\,(2-v)-u^2)}
      \right)
\tag{2phi}\label{2phi}
.
\end{align}

Numerical tests demonstrate that in general 
expressions \eqref{2a}-\eqref{2c}
work fine for the valid range of $u,\,v$, 
except for
an annoying special case, 
which corresponds to equilateral triangle,
when $v=\tfrac12$, $u=\tfrac{3\sqrt3}2$,
$a=b=c=\tfrac23\,u\,R$.
In this case \eqref{1} collapses to

\begin{align}
(x-\sqrt3)^3&=0
\tag{3}\label{3}
\end{align}

and direct numeric calculation of $\phi$ fails.

Of course, it's not a big deal and this case can be algorithmically isolated and handled differently,
but,

**the question** is: Is it possible to come up with some modified version
of expression for $\phi$, which would work
gracefully for all valid pairs of $u,\,v$?

This probably could be useful:
the valid range is found as follows: for $v\in(0,\tfrac12]$,

\begin{align}
u&\in[u_{\min},u_{\max}]
,\\
u_{\min}(v)&=
\sqrt{27-(5-v)^2-2\,\sqrt{(1-2\,v)^3}}
,\\
u_{\max}(v)&=
\sqrt{27-(5-v)^2+2\,\sqrt{(1-2\,v)^3}}
.
\end{align}

Both boundary curves $u_{\max}(v)$ and $u_{\min}(v)$, 
correspond to isosceles triangles,
$u_{\max}(v)$ represents all isosceles triangles 
with the base as the smallest side,
while 
$u_{\min}(v)$ represents all isosceles triangles 
with the base as the largest side.
The area, bounded by $u_{\min}(v)$, $u_{\max}(v)$
and the $u$-axis covers all possible types of valid triangles
with $R=1$ and can be used as a "map of the Trianglia"
to make a quick crude tests of some general properties of triangles,
for example, to estimate $\max(\sin\alpha+\sin\beta+\sin\gamma)$, etc.

Comment: Triangles aside, you are effectively asking for a universal solution to the (depressed) cubic $t^3+pt+q=0$ that works even when $p=q=0$. I'm personally not aware of one. Solutions such as [those in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation) separate-out such special cases. (For completeness: Your cubic's corresponding "depressed" coefficients are $$p=\frac13\left(3r^2+12\rho R-\rho^2\right)=-\frac13\left(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca\right)$$ $$q= \frac2{27}\rho\left(9r^2-18rR+\rho^2\right)=-\frac1{27}(2a-b-c)(-a+2b-c)(-a-b+2c)$$ which (obviously) vanish when $a=b=c$.)

Comment: @Blue: Good point. So, it hardly possible to find such a modification.
OK, thanks, you can make it an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Converting comment to answer, as requested.)

Triangles aside, you are effectively asking for a universal solution to the (depressed) cubic $t^3+pt+q=0$ that works even when $p=q=0$. I'm personally not aware of one. Solutions such as [those in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation) separate-out such special cases. (Of course, when $p=0$, the solution is clear enough not to *need* a "formula".)

For completeness: Your cubic's corresponding "depressed" coefficients are
$$\begin{align}
p &=\frac13 (3v^2+12 v-u^2) = \frac1{3R^2}\left(3r^2+12\rho R−\rho^2\right) \\[6pt]
&=−\frac1{3R^2}\left(a^2+b^2+c^2−ab−bc−ca\right) \\[10pt]
q 
&=\frac2{27} u \left(u^2 - 18 v + 9 v^2\right) = \frac2{27R^3}\rho\left(9r^2−18rR+ρ^2\right) \\[6pt]
&=−\frac1{27R^3}(2a−b−c)(−a+2b−c)(−a−b+2c)
\end{align}$$
which (obviously) vanish when $a=b=c$.

Note that (a multiple of) $\sqrt{-p}$ is the coefficient of the $\cos(\phi+\cdots)$ terms in OP's expressions for the roots. So, maybe the fact that the $\phi$ formula fails when $p=0$ doesn't *really* matter, since those terms simply vanish.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT1:

Not an answer really. As an aside like to how geometrically how $ (R,r,\rho?,a,b,c) $ can be represented by a  polar diagram from a cubic.

Mathematica outputs a big analytical solution.. may be relatable to *irreducible case* of Cardano's solution of the cubic equation.. that yields three real roots.

$ (R,r,s) = (4.04145, 0.866025, 7.5)$ numerical values belong to an obtuse angled triangle of sides and semi-perimeter $(a= 7, b= 5,c= 3, \rho=7.5)$

Comment: Eq.(1) is straightforward, since $a+b+c=2\rho$,
$ab+bc+ca=\rho^2+r^2+4rR$, $abc=4\rho rR$.
And yes, for the $3-5-7$ triangle we have 
$\rho=\tfrac{15}2$,
$r=\tfrac12\sqrt3$, 
$R=\tfrac73\sqrt3$,
$u=\tfrac{15}{14}\,\sqrt3$,
$v=\tfrac3{14}$,
$\phi=\tfrac\pi6$
and eqns (2a-2c) work perfectly.

Comment: Yes,deviated in thought about  the irreducible case geometric representation away from $ \Sigma ab $ algebra calculation. Still feel like posing a question  here.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to *test* for the possibility that we will get an undefined or ill-conditioned expression for $\phi$.

When er have an equilateral triangle, the multiplier $\sqrt{u^2-3v(v+4)}$ vanishes. So we test whether the radicand $u^2-3v(v+4)$ is close to zero ("close" to be defined by the user, based on for instance computer precision), and if so we will default to the equilateral solution.